# Vaadin Grid - Attempted to fetch more items from server than allowed in one go

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

~1500 data need to be fetched from DB. The code is pretty simple

```
List<Item> itemList = getItemsFromDB();
Grid<Item> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addColumn(Item::getID).setHeader("Id").setAutoWidth(true);
grid.addColumn(Item::getName).setHeader("Name").setAutoWidth(true);       
grid.setAllRowsVisible(true);
grid.setItems(itemList);
```

And I got this warning, only the first 1000 data are shown in the grid, the rest are just empty rows.

```
2022-04-15 15:46:52.475  WARN 19642 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.v.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator  : Attempted to fetch more items from server than allowed in one go: number of items requested '1583', maximum items allowed '1000'.
```

I know I can use lazy loading, but can I do it without it? The size of data will always be around 1500, and I don't actually care that much about how slow it is.

I am using vaadin 14.8.8

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code for how you set up and populate the grid so it's easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarcusHellberg added some code for how I used the grid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from setAllRowsVisible and the [DoS protection added](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/12238) inside the data provider. It's currently not easily possible to overwrite this without creating your own data provider.

I'm not really sure why you need all the rows visible; this increases the load time for your end user. If your only reason is to have the grid full height, you can just call setHeight on the grid and the let Vaadin handle the callbacks to the server to only fetch the amount of data needed to show on the client.

Comment: Having the grid full height is not my intention. Like I said in the question, the user will not care about the load time, they are very patient :). What we want is they can sort the whole list and do searching via `ctrl + F`, which callbacks are not ideal in this case.

Comment: Thanks for linking the PR in reply, nothing in the doc brings up the 1000 limit. However, the number 1000 itself doesn't make any sense, even the intention of adding DoS protection does.

Comment: Not really a solution but a workaround you could try (untested; just an idea): you could try to set the page size of the data provider to something like 900-999 and check if that's enough for your use case that the grid loads all data because the grid normally loads the page plus a buffer for smooth scrolling